Integration inequality involving square root of polynomial
I need to estimate an upper bound for a sum involving fractional power for a paper I am writing. I did some numerical testing and it seems that
$$\int_{x-1/2}^{x+1/2}\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}y^5+10y^4+\frac{89}{3}y^3+\frac{79}{2}y^2+\frac{39}{2}y}\mathop{dy}\geq \sqrt{\frac{4}{3}x^5+10x^4+\frac{89}{3}x^3+\frac{79}{2}x^2+\frac{39}{2}x},$$
for $x>1$, but I am not sure how to prove it. My guess is that it has to do with the large exponent inside the square root, which makes the polynomial concave, but I don't see how to use that.

The function $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}x^5+10x^4+\frac{89}{3}x^3+\frac{79}{2}x^2+\frac{39}{2}x}\,$ is convex to the right of $1/2$, as its second derivative is positive in $[1/2,+\infty)$, which can be checked graphically.
Now, it is known (in fact, it is a special case of Jensen's inequality) that if a function $f$ is convex on $[a,b]$ then $$f\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)\leq \dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\, dx$$
Taking $a=x-1/2$, $b=x+1/2$ we have that $f$ is convex on $[a,b]$ (as $x>1$, $x-1/2>1/2$), $\dfrac{a+b}{2}=x$ and $b-a=1$. Consequently,
$$ \sqrt{\frac{4}{3}x^5+10x^4+\frac{89}{3}x^3+\frac{79}{2}x^2+\frac{39}{2}x}\leq \int_{x-1/2}^{x+1/2}\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}y^5+10y^4+\frac{89}{3}y^3+\frac{79}{2}y^2+\frac{39}{2}y}\,\mathop{dy}$$
